# Как создать screen, если тот отсутствует?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

Я создаю screen такой командой:

```
screen -dmS screen_name command
```

Но если выполнить эту команду несколько раз, тогда будет создано несколько одноименных screen.

Я хочу, чтобы screen не создавался, если уже имеется screen с таким именем.

Конечно можно сделать дополнительную проверку:

```
if screen -ls | grep -q "\.screen_name\s"; then
  exit 0;
fi
screen -dmS screen_name command
```

Но возможно ли это сделать каким либо из аргументов команды screen?

Я видел, что существуют аргументы по типу таких:

```
-d -r
    Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first. 
-d -R
    Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first. 
-d -RR
    Reattach a session and if necessary detach or create it. Use the first session if more than
    one session is available. 
-D -r
    Reattach a session. If necessary detach and logout remotely first. 
-D -R
    Attach here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach. If necessary
    detach and logout remotely first. If it was not running create it and notify the user. This is
    the author's favorite. 
-D -RR
    Attach here and now. Whatever that means, just do it. 
    Note: It is always a good idea to check the status of your sessions by means of "screen -list".
```

Но я хочу создавать screen в "detached" режиме, а эти все аргументы делают attach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255388

Comment: там нет ответа, который удовлетворяет моим требованиям. 1) без дополнительного if. 2) в "detached" режиме.

Comment: Чем вам не угодил дополнительный if?

Comment: во первых, мне просто не нравится, во вторых, такой вариант использования не является потокобезопасным

Comment: Тогда осмелюсь предположить, что вы используете screen не по назначению. Если вам вдруг стала нужна потокобезопасность, вы определённо делаете что-то ну крайне странное

Comment: в screen я запускаю демон приложения. я не хочу, чтобы приложение запустилось дважды

Comment: Для запуска демонов существуют специальные менеджеры процессов (systemd, supervisord и т.п.), screen для этого не предназначен

Comment: мне нравится screen, я не хочу другое. но тем не менее я пробовал systemd, он мне не походит

Comment: Вы несколько комментариев назад написали, что вам «просто не нравится». Но если вы намеренно хотите продолжать использовать совершенно не подходящий для этого инструмент — что ж, нам остаётся только посочувствовать ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: мне бы пришлось сочувствовать еще больше, если бы я использовал systemd. приходится выбирать лучшее из худшего

Comment: Можно запускать демоны и просто так из других скриптов, только часто это совершенно неверный подход, ну и микроскопом гвозди...

Comment: мне не важно, что верно, а что неверно. есть задачи, а есть решения. screen решает мою задачу, а systemctl - нет

Comment: `мне не важно, что верно, а что неверно`. Воу-воу-воу, парень, палехше. Это путь к убогой архитектуре, которая потом подарит множество радостных моментов как будущему тебе, так и тем, кто будет это сопровождать после тебя. Не ты первый, не ты последний, кто думает, что "мой велосипед - самый лучший, а все остальные просто не шарят как правильно".

Comment: Если ты таки всё равно хочешь использовать менеджер терминалов в качестве системы управления службами (кстати, ответь, как ты собрался обрабатывать запись событий в журнал и реагировать на падение твоей приложухи), то можно попробовать ещё `tmux`.

Comment: @donRumata нет. я так не думаю, это ваши домыслы. но я не буду использовать решение, которое мне не подходит, даже если оно "правильное". логгирование ведется самим приложением. за подъем в случае падения отвечает другое приложение. я пробовал tmux, он хуже решает мою задачу, чем screen.

Comment: `за подъем в случае падения отвечает другое приложение`, о, ты начал писать свою систему управления службами. Ну тогда я решительно не понимаю, чем тебе не подходит ещё один `if-then`, раз у тебя уже велобаза.

Comment: я не начал. этой системе уже 4 года. я уже говорил, зачем `во первых, мне просто не нравится, во вторых, такой вариант использования не является потокобезопасным`. даже если бы не было второй причины, мне бы хватило первой для написания вопроса. или научный интерес тут не приветствуется?

Comment: `этой системе уже 4 года`, оххх, сочувствую. `не является потокобезопасным` - стесняюсь спросить: а как запуск внутри `screen` делает прогу потокобезопасной, а те же systemd\supervisord\sysv\openrc этого НЕ делают? Мы же щас про https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-safety говорим?

Comment: хватит выдумывать вещи, которые я не говорил. про потокобезопасность systemd и screen я ничего не говорил. я говорил `такой вариант использования не является потокобезопасным`, речь идет о дополнительном `if`

Comment: А, значит я неправильно прочёл. Ок, сорян.